# How to reference a subview without outlet

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, subview

Just beginning with iPhone development i seem to miss something fundamental.

In a View based application i'm adding programaticaly a UIView subclass in the ViewController implementation file and can set a value:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

 CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(20, 50, 250, 320);

 GraphView *graphView = [[GraphView alloc] initWithFrame:myRect];

 [self.view addSubview:graphView];

    graphView.myString = @"Working here";

}
```

When i try to change the same value with an action in the same file, the Build fails because graphView is undeclared:

```
- (void)puschButton1 {


 graphView.myString = @"Not working here";

}
```

Because I use a UIView subclass there is no outlet for my GraphView instance.

How can i get a reference to my subview? Or should this be done in another way?

Thanks in advance

Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to make `graphView` an instance variable for your view controller, instead of declaring it in `viewDidLoad`.

Put something like this in your `.h` file:

```
@class GraphView;

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    GraphView *graphView;
}

// ... method declarations ...

@end
```

If you don't want to do that, another way is to set `graphView`'s `tag` property, and then call the superview's `viewWithTag:` method to retrieve the view when you need it.

I'm not sure what you mean by "Because I use a UIView subclass there is no outlet for my GraphView instance." You generally declare outlets on your controller class, and it doesn't matter whether you are using a subclass of `UIView`.

As an aside, I'll note that you should probably `release` that `GraphView` at some point, or you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! The Compiler complains with:
warning: local declaration of 'graphView' hides instance variable
with the addSubview Statement.

Comment: That's because you still have this line: "GraphView *graphView = [[GraphView alloc] initWithFrame:myRect];" Change it to: self.graphView = [[GraphView alloc] initWithFrame:myRect];

Comment: David, you made my day! :-) THAT was the fundamental thing i was missing! Thanks a lot Kristopher, David and Sam.

Answer (score 0):

You could store `graphView` as a class variable.

EDIT: note that `addSubview` will increase the retain count of the object, somewhere in your class you will need to balance the `alloc` with a `release` and the `addSubview` with a `removeFromSuperview` or a `release`.